# Airflow Rotating encryption keys

Tags: python, airflow

Hey guys I was looking into rotating encryption keys within Airflow and was a little confused on their documentation located here: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/secure-connections.html

The steps are as followed:

```
Set fernet_key to new_fernet_key,old_fernet_key

Run airflow rotate_fernet_key to re-encrypt existing credentials with the new fernet key

Set fernet_key to new_fernet_key
```

I'm confused on what we are supposed to do on the first step. Are supposed to set fernet_key to both new_fernet_key and old_fernet_key. Also I was wondering if it were possible to write a script that automates all of this so that I could simply run the file and it would properly rotate encryption keys rather than producing a new_fernet_key every time I need want it and manually putting into the Airflow.cfg file. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the documentation is certainly a bit confusing, I explain how you can  rotate the fernet key in Airflow running on a Kubernetes cluster (I am using version 1.10.14).

If you look at [how the fernet key is set in AIRFLOW](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/925ef281856630f5231baf42a30a5eb18f0b7ca0/airflow/models/crypto.py#L86), it uses the [MultiFernet class](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.MultiFernet) which expects two fernet keys that in this case must be given as value (separated by comma) for the Airflow fernet key configuration parameter. So:

1. Generate a new fernet key as [explained in the documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/fernet.html#generating-fernet-key).
2. Stop your Airflow scheduler service in k8s.
3. Set the value of the fernet key (through your configmap or whatever method you use to pass the `AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY` env value) as `ThisIsObviouslyAFakeNEWFernetKeyUJ_65Hgdjsmg=,ThisIsObviouslyAFakeOLDFernetKeyOP_78KufGSd3=` (new_fernet_key,old_fernet_key).
4. Relaunch you scheduler or deploy the whole Airflow.
5. Ssh into the scheduler pod and run `airflow rotate-fernet-key`.
6. Exit the pod and bring down your scheduler again.
7. Set the value of `AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY` to
   `ThisIsObviouslyAFakeNEWFernetKeyUJ_65Hgdjsmg=` (only the new fernet
   key).
8. Relaunch your scheduler service.

And that should re-encrypt all your variables and connections using the new fernet key without having to reset your metastore database.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice will be to set it externally as env_var.
Then while rebooting the system there's no need to rotate at all.

As stated in the doc it's risky to rotate fernet keys because:

> changing the key will cause decryption of existing credentials to
> fail.

Something like

```
fernet_key = $FERNET_KEY
```